# How do i slow down physics?

Tags: animation, physics, frame-rate

I want to know how to slow down physics simulations or at least the explosion modifier.

I want to know this so i can render out the explosion with a high fps but over a longer period of time so i can slow it down and still keep the animation smooth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using **Rigid Bodies**, you can just decrease **Speed** in **Rigid Body World** settings under **Scene tab**:

[image: 1]

You can also increase **Step Per Second** and **Solver Itarations** to get smoother and more detailed simulations.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention the explosion modifier, which is controlled by a particle system, you'll need to slow down the particles. This can be achieved in a number of ways, for example by adjusting the forces (e.g. gravity and/or force fields) affecting the particles. The most direct way is to lower the time between frames while increasing the number of frames. This is easily done in the particle settings.

[image]

Let's say, for example, that you have a 10 second animation at 25 fps, and you want to render it over 40 seconds. The settings in the image should then be changed as follows.

Under *Emission* change the following
*Start* should remain set to 1.000 since the first frame will of course be frame 1 regardless of the speed; if you simulation starts at a later frame, the new start frame can be calculated like this: <new start frame> = 1+4*(<old start frame>-1).
*End*: 800.000 (=200.000*4)
*Lifetime*: 200.000 (=50.000*4)
*Random* shouldn't need to be changed, as it's a percentage.
*Number* should be fine as is, but may need some tweaking.

Under *Physics* change *Timestep* to 0.010 (=0.040/4).
*Subframes* shouldn't need to be changed, and you may even be able to lower it, since you now have more real frames. Subframes are only used in calculations, and are never rendered or even cached. A typical use case is to prevent fast moving particles from passing through a collision object.

Don't forget to also change the number of frames to render in the *Render* tab appropriately (1000 in this example), but leave the framerate unchanged (25 fps in this example).